# what's the meaning of "have something on edge"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases

> Syndrome, or MERS, outbreak, which has Korea on edge.

What's the meaning of a phrase "have something on edge"?

I know that 'on edge' means being worried or anxious.

Does it mean that MERS makes Korea worried?

Comment: yes, it made Korea [worried/tense](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+edge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Subj HAVE Obj Compl* is a sort of "stative" version of causative *Subj MAKE Obj Compl*.

The *MAKE* construction names an event whose result is that *Obj* enters the state expressed by *Compl*. If *MAKE* is in the simple present it implies repeated events and consequences:

> George made Mary nervous. ... *That is, on one occasion Mary became nervous as a result of something George said or did*.
>
> George makes Mary nervous. ... *That is, whenever George is present Mary becomes nervous*.

The *HAVE* construction is understood not so much as an event as a situation which causes *Obj* to be continuously in the state expressed by *Compl*.

> George has Mary nervous. ... *That is, Mary is always nervous as a result of something George did or does*.

The sense of your sentence, then, is that Korea is currently and continuously on edge because of the MERS outbreak.

*Compl* may also be an infinitive or gerund clause; the two have very different  senses.

- An infinitive clause designates a single perfective (completed) event performed by *Obj* at *Subj*'s explicit request or order.

  > George had Mary check her math. ... *That is, George told Mary to check her math on a particular occasion.*

  If *HAVE* is in the simple present, *Obj* performs this action repeatedly or habitually.

  > George has Mary check her math. ... *That is, George has established that Mary is to check her math on each occasion.*
- A gerund clause designates an imperfective (not completed) activity—in effect, a state of activity—which *Obj* is continuously performing at the time in question. This activity may have been expressly ordered or requested by *Subj*, or it may have been undertaken in response to something entirely different done by *Subj*.

  > George has Mary checking her math. ... *This may merely report that Mary is currently engaged in the check George ordered; or it may report that something George said or did has Mary so uncertain that she is constantly checking her math to make sure she hasn't made mistakes.*